# Create 50 Nodes in Cypher with for each

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to create 50 nodes with just one Cypher statement. 
Each node should have a property with a number from 1 to 50.

The expected result is:

```
(:Slot{number:1}), (:Slot{number:2}), (:Slot{number:3}), ...
```

Any Suggestions?

#### Part2:

Each of these nodes should get a relationship with another node.
50 Slots are in 1 Box
[Diagram Link](http://scribd.com/document/438557768/Untitled-Diagram)

`MATCH (s:Slot)
 CREATE (b:Box{number:1})
 WITH MAX(s.number) AS maxSlotNumber
 WITH COALESCE(maxSlotNumber, 0) AS lastExistingSlotNumber
 FOREACH (i in range(lastExistingSlotNumber+1, lastExistingSlotNumber+50) | 
 CREATE (:Slot {number: i}))`.

This is my code right now and i want that all this slots get a relationship with b at the time of creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could approach it - `FOREACH` is the shortest:

```
FOREACH (i in range(1, 50) | MERGE (:Slot { number: i }))
```

Or you could `UNWIND` an array of integers created by the `range` this way:

```
UNWIND range(1, 50) AS i
MERGE (:Slot { number: i })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, that is exactly what i was looking for but to be honest i dont really understand your argument in the second way.
Could you please explain the difference between these 2 ways ?

Comment: I removed the comment as it's inaccurate and somewhat confusing

Comment: Now i face an other problem, what if i would like that these nodes get a relationship with an other node ? 
What i mean: 50 slot nodes get a relationship [:in_Box] with one only node that is called box.
Because in real life my boxes have 50 slots

Comment: You need to either raise a new question or edit more information into the original one I think, need an example (maybe a diagram) of how you expect the end result to look

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/438557768/Untitled-Diagram

 ofc there are 50 slots but i just draw 3.
on time of creation i just would like all the 50 slots  to get a relationship with the box node

Comment: i updated the main question, maybe this helps you to understand

Comment: As @Pablissimo stated, you should create a new question (with the appropriate information).